# jQuery draggable background image with pin moveable base on draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have jQuery draggable image background.

Now I put sample 1 pin there with name : `I'm Pin`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    const container = document.querySelector('.img');
    const containerSize = container.getBoundingClientRect();

    let imagePosition = { x: 50, y: 50 };
    let cursorPosBefore = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    let imagePosBefore = null;
    let imagePosAfter = imagePosition;

    // Helpers
    const minMax = (pos) => (pos < 0) ? 0 : (pos > 100) ? 100 : pos;
    const setNewCenter = (x, y) => {
      imagePosAfter = { x: x, y: y }; 
      container.style.backgroundPosition = `${x}% ${y}%`;
    };

    const getImageZoom = () => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let actualImage = new Image();
        actualImage.src = $('#img').css('background-image').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");
        actualImage.onload = function() {
          resolve({
            x: zoomX = this.width / containerSize.width - 1,
            y: zoomY = this.height / containerSize.height - 1
          });
        }
      });
    }
        
    const addEventListeners = (zoomLevels) => {container.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
          cursorPosBefore = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
          imagePosBefore = imagePosAfter; // Get current image position
        });

        container.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            if (event.buttons === 0) return;

            let newXPos = imagePosBefore.x + ((cursorPosBefore.x - event.clientX) / containerSize.width * 100 / zoomLevels.x);
            let newYPos = imagePosBefore.y + ((cursorPosBefore.y - event.clientY) / containerSize.height * 100 / zoomLevels.y);

            setNewCenter(minMax(newXPos), minMax(newYPos));
        });
    };

    getImageZoom().then(zoom => addEventListeners(zoom));
});
```

```css
#img {
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
  height: calc(100vh - 25px);
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-image: url('https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/502/954/png-transparent-world-map-world-map-miscellaneous-world-map.png');
  cursor: move;
  border: 3px solid #5e5e5e;
}

#img:active {
  border-color: #007fff;
}

.pin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 400px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img" id="img">
  <div class="pin">I'm PIN</div>
</div>
```

As you can see on above code demo, `I'm Pin` should be inside of class `img` but now it's outside. Also when I try to drag the area, the text `I'm Pin` should be follow with the background image move.

My question is:

1. How to make the `I'm Pin` is not over the `img`?
2. How to make the `I'm Pin` move base on draggable background image?

Comment: do `position: relative;` for `.pin {`

Comment: same, still not working.

Comment: I'm Pin should be inside of class img but now it's outside.
How to make the I'm Pin is not over the img?
It's a bit unlear what you trying to acheive, you want the text to be placed on a certain country?